# Copy and rename multiple files in multiple directories with windows CMD line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, rename

I want to copy and rename files that are stored in a stack of directories (year, month, day). The files are `.ers` files and I need them to maintain their extension but to go from `file.ers` to `file_cloud.ers`.
Then I would like the files for a given month to be saved in the `cloud` folder within each month.
Ideally I would do this in the Windows Command Line.
I understand a batch file is a good place to start, and so I have the following - this doesn't include saving in a different location - but I am struggling with just the copy and rename.

```
for /D %%y in ("C:\Data\20*") do (
    pushd "%%~y"
    for /D %%m in ("*") do (
        pushd "%%~m"
        for /D %%d in ("*") do (
            pushd "%%~d"
            for %%f in (soig_*.ers) do copy "%%~f.ers" "%%~f_cloud.ers"
            popd
        ) 
        popd
    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help, particularly the part with the `~` modifiers...

Comment: Insert an echo in front of the copy and see what has to be changed.

Comment: Do you want the renamed files to be copied from the day folder to a new `cloud` folder that resides within the month folder, or do you want the day folder to be copied into the `cloud` folder as well? for example: `2017\04\25\soig_file.ers` to `2017\04\cloud\soig_file_cloud.ers`, or `2017\04\25\soig_file.ers` to `2017\04\cloud\25\soig_file_cloud.ers`?

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier than you are making it. If this echos the correct copy command, remove the `echo`. You get this by sticking your head way down into the output of `FOR /?`.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /S /B /A:-D "*.ers"`) DO (
    echo COPY "%%~f" "%%~dpnf_cloud.%%~xf"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work okay for you, *(it is supposed to copy all matching .ers files with updated names to the **existing** cloud directory at the previous level of their tree)*.

```bat
@FOR /D %%Y IN ("C:\Data\20*") DO @FOR /D %%M IN ("%%Y\*"
) DO @FOR /D %%D IN ("%%M\*") DO @IF /I NOT "%%~nxD"=="cloud" FOR %%F IN (
    "%%~D\soig_*.ers") DO @COPY "%%F" "%%~M\cloud\%%~nFcloud%%~xF">NUL
```

*I have not included anything to prevent overwrites of files whose names already exist within that cloud directory*